# Notifications with Checklist in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am sorry I dont know anything about coding but I am desperate to create a specific functionality. I want to create a checklist in a Google Doc and when different check boxes are checked it automatically prompts email notifications to different addresses. Can Google Apps Script do this? Can somehow help me understand how? Thank you!

Scott,

Comment: It would be much easier to  perform in Google Spreadsheet rather than Google Documents.

Comment: There is no onEdit(e) in Google Doc like there is in Google Spreadsheet, so if someone checks a box nothing will happen unless you install a custom menu item and that is triggered.

Comment: This could be done either in a dialog or a sidebar what are some of the details you want?

Answer (score 0):

#### Email Dialog

Code.gs:

```
function displayCheckBoxes(chA) {
  var ss=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var html='';
  for(var i=0;i<chA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />%s', chA[i].value);
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Checked Boxes');
}

function launchCheckboxDialog() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'),'Email Dialog');
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="Checks" value="Email 1 Sent" /><label for="chk1">Send Email 1</label>
   <br /><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="Checks" value="Email 2 Sent" /><label for="chk2">Send Email 2</label>
   <br /><input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="Checks" value="Email 3 Sent" /><label for="chk3">Send Email 3</label>
   <br /><input type="button" id="chkbtn" value="Send Selected Emails" onClick="saveChecks();" />

   <script>
     function saveChecks() {
    var chA=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name="Checks"]:checked');
    var cbA=[];
    console.log('Checkboxes: %s',JSON.stringify(chA));
    for(var i=0;i<chA.length;i++) {
      console.log('id: %s name: %s value: %s',chA[i].id,chA[i].name,chA[i].value);
      cbA.push({id:chA[i].id,name:chA[i].name,value:chA[i].value});
    }
    google.script.run.displayCheckBoxes(cbA);
  }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]